# want to write a csv file but get a chain of chars and comas

Tags: python, csv

I may do not know exactly how to search the forum, have not been sucesfull to find an answer to solve my current problem. Trying to write to a csv file in python3, with the following code

```
for row in Lista_Original:
    if row not in No_Duplicados:
        if row=="Puesto/JobTitle":
            continue
        No_Duplicados.append(row)
        #print('\n',row,'   ',print(row[0]))
        if not os.path.isfile(filepath):
            with open(filepath, mode='w+', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as f:
                writer = csv.writer(f)
                writer.writerow(header)
        print('\nLos datos x escribir:',row,'\n','el otro caso',row[0])
        continuar=input('Desea continuar:')
        with open(filepath, mode='a+', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as f:
            writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=',')
            writer.writerow(row.split())
            ndndcount+=1
```

this is an example of what I am gettin

G,E,R,E,N,T,E, ,D,E, ,O,P,E,R,A,C,I,O,N,E,S, ,(,A,G,E,N,C,I,A, ,A,D,U,A,N,A,L,)

I was expecting

GERENTE DE OPERACIONES (AGENCIA ADUANAL)

I did try

```
writer.writerow(row)

writer.writerow(row[0])

writer.writerow([row])
```

as alternatives but did not work. So conclusio: I do not know what I am doing, what make this more difficult is i do not know programing, or computer science, i try to learn but sometimes some subjects are ver complex, some of the code lines were added when I was trying to find out what is wrong like

```
print('\nLos datos x escribir:',row,'\n','el otro caso',row[0])
```

I will appreciate any help pointing me to a text, training or material that can helpe me
(for the event that someone may not notice english is not my language)

Comment: Please, provide example files, at least, so people can test your code and figure it out. It seems simple read/write logic should suffice. Maybe try a simple tutorial on files with Python, as [this one](https://realpython.com/read-write-files-python/).

Comment: could you show us exactly what one of the row values is. like just 'print(row)'. ?

Comment: this is an example of what I am getting

G,E,R,E,N,T,E, ,D,E, ,O,P,E,R,A,C,I,O,N,E,S, ,(,A,G,E,N,C,I,A, ,A,D,U,A,N,A,L,) what I was expecting is GERENTE DE OPERACIONES (AGENCIA ADUANAL)

Comment: I end up changing the code to get the result iwas looking for but not sure hiw to add it in here